# How to concatenate variable name with for loop variable using python and tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to add the **"i"** for loop variable with a variabel name.

```
def get_or_refresh_call_list(self, event=None): 
            
    #get dates
    call_dates_webElements = self.get_elements(self.call_dates)
        
    for i in range(len(call_dates_webElements)):
                
        temp_var = 'self.date_label_call_' + f"{i}"
        temp_var.config(text=call_dates_webElements[i].text)
```

The first variable name would be `self.date_label_call_1` and the second would be '
`self.date_label_call_2` and so on.

The error I get is: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'config'`

Comment: Try `temp_var = eval(f'self.date_label_call_{i+1}')` instead.  Note that `{i+1}` is used because your variable names start from `_1`.

Comment: Using `eval` is dangerous, but you can use `setattr` instead: `setattr(self, f"date_label_call_{i+1}", "<the text here>")`

Comment: This is a bad practice. Instead of computing dynamic variable names, your code will be much easier to write and debug if you store your data in a dictionary. See [How do I create variable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: Although I answered the question as asked, I fully agree with you @BryanOakley. A dict, or maybe a list in this case, would be a much better design for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to set attributes inside a class when you need to construct their name on the fly is to use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=setattr#setattr). That's exactly what it's for. And later, if you want to read the attribute values in a similar programmatic way, use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=setattr#getattr).

In your code, that means:

```
    for i in range(len(call_dates_webElements)):
        temp_var = 'date_label_call_' + f"{i+1}"
        temp_text = call_dates_webElements[i].text
        setattr(self, temp_var, temp_text)
```

or just

```
    for i in range(len(call_dates_webElements)):
        setattr(self, f"date_label_call_{i+1}", call_dates_webElements[i].text)
```

Notes:

- I'm using `i+1` for the variable name: as @acw1668 pointed out in the comment, your loop will start at 0, but in the question you say you want your variables to start at `_1`.
- I removed `self.` from `temp_var`: `setattr` will already add the attribute to `self`, so I just need to provide the attribute name.
- You can later access these attributes as `self.date_label_call_1` if you want to hardcode the name, or with `getattr(self, f"date_label_call_{i+1}") in a loop over` i`.
- That `getattr` call will raise an exception if the attribute has not been set before, but you can give it a default value to return instead when the attribute is not defined, e.g., `getattr(self, f"date_label_call_{i+1}", "no such date label call found")`.

Answer (score 0):

It’s due to you calling the `config` function on the string data type `temp_var`:

```
temp_var.config(text=call_dates_webElements[i].text)
```